# What MySQL Date/Time type do you use in your applications and why?

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, actionscript-3

I've always just kind of randomly chosen DATETIME or TIMESTAMP. What are the pros/cons of each and what do you use and why? (I realize some have more detail, I'm usually looking for year/month/day/hour/minute/second resolution and I'm currently working with PHP, AS3, and Objective-C.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp can be updated/created automatically and can reflect on changing the timezone mysql session variable. Also `date` can store the dates of wider range (2038 vs 9999).

As for me - I prefer to use timestamp everywhere, since it is easy to display the time in user's timezone.

```
SET time_zone='$tz'
```

Where $tz is an offset in format `+10:00` or string timezone representation like `Asia/Vladivostok`. After you perform this query - all the dates will be automatically converted to expected timezone. And from another point of view - each date you're storing in database will be stored with a glance of current timezone. (`timestamp` is stored in UTC, and mysql just offsets it when returns data to you, according the `time_zone` variable).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html

Comment: Oh interesting. So in PHP how would you change the session timezone? And if you did a select on a timezone it would auto-convert to that session timezone?

Comment: @jestro: yep. I've given a short description.